# Katalon Studio Can Not Start Recording or Spy Object for Mobile Android Devices

Tags: android, macos, automation, appium, katalon-studio

I received this error like the following pictures:
[image]
[image]
I have installed all required Prerequisites explained here: https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/tutorials/get-started/set-up-mobile-automation-project-macos/

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I have to support node version 8. So, I downgraded my node and it's working just fine.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your katalon studio and usb debugging on the device.